# JsonPath how to add multiple elements and compare one of elements

Tags: json, jsonpath

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": 20,
        "b": 30,
        "c": 40
    }
}
```

My query expression: `$.data[?(@.a < (@.b + @.c))]`

I hope it will return the following result: `{"a": 20}`

But this way the following error will occur:

```
Failed to parse filter: [?(@.a < (@.b + @.c))], error on position: 9, char: (
```

What is the correct expression?

Comment: What's the error that occours?

Comment: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected character (,) at position 60.

Comment: it's a typo. it should be "c": 40, not "c",40

Comment: I corrected the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

correct your json string as `"c":40`

You can convert json string to JavaObject using ObjectMapper,
Java objects representing your json string

```
public class Data{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}

public class Root{
    public Data data;
}
```

then you can access data as below which maps`myJsonString` to java object, `root` has all data

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class);
```